# how to merge a new table into an exist one without put into same form?

Tags: html

I have a question here and wondering if you could provide your help.
how I could merge second "stage" entries as a vertical table to the right side of the table IP_address ?
I don't want them merge into same  , because that will cause some issue.
thank you in advance.

```html
<table width="100%" class="table" >
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th >IP</th>
           <th >Stage</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="{{url_for('show_select')}}" method="post">
  {% for entry in entries %}
      <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="IP" name="IP" class="IPS" value="{{entry.ip_address}}" readonly>
        </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
  {%endfor %}
</form>


{% for entry in entries %}
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div id="f1_container" name="container">
    <div id="cube" class="cube" >
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--stage_1">
        <input id="stage_1" type="button" class="btn-default" name="stage" value="test" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
{%endfor %}

</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `form` can not be a child of `tbody`

Comment: I have remove the tbody but no difference.

Comment: It was not supposed to solve your issue. Just feedback on your markup. If you want to have any element like `<form>` within a table beside the table-specific elements it has to be inside a `<td>`

Comment: sorry , I just can't get your point.

Comment: You appear to be using a template engine, please use the tag of the engine or platform on which you're executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

What Pablo was trying to point out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634699/how-to-merge-a-new-table-into-an-exist-one-without-put-into-same-form/57635734#comment101722540_57634699) was that the `<form>` HTML element is not a valid descendant of [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody). The documentation states under "Permitted content":

> Zero or more `<tr>` elements.

Which means having a form directly inside a `<tbody>` is invalid markup, and as such can lead to unexpected behavior.

The option I see fit your use case best would be using the [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form) attribute of the input element. However, unless the input has the type `submit` you won't be able to submit the form with it without the use of JavaScript.

For the `form` attribute to work you will need to generate a unique ID for each form and use it when generating the code. Due the lack of a template engine tag this solution will assume the use of [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) (based on the syntax and the `url_for` call), but the concept should be the same for any other template language.

Your two options are to either use the iterator variable to make sequential IDs, or if your records have one, use a unique ID from the records themselves. For this solution I will use the loop variable to generate the IDs.

```
<table width="100%" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>Stage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- moved form inside the table cell, gave it a unique ID -->
        <form id="myform-{{loop.index0}}" name="myform" action="{{url_for('show_select')}}" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="IP" name="IP" class="IPS" value="{{entry.ip_address}}" readonly>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="f1_container" name="container">
          <div id="cube" class="cube">
            <div class="cube__face cube__face--stage_1">
              <!-- type changed to submit, added form attribute matching the value given to the form's id attribute -->
              <input type="submit" form="myform-{{loop.index0}}" class="btn-default" name="stage" value="test">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi SeinopSys, Thanks a lot for your analyze and explanation. but I might not use cube as a submit type. I need other function to trigger that.I actually need something like below that has 2 separate page. :https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float

Comment: @The_flash In JavaScript you can listen to the `submit` event of the generated forms to avoid a page reload and do whatever you want the page to do instead, but that would be outside the scope of this question. Please make an attempt to do it yourself and if you get stuck ask a new question.